# Replace exponential values to double in mathematical expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex, evaluation, expression-evaluation

I need to check if a mathematical expression contains a exponential value and then replace the exponential value with decimal value.

Input :"10993.657030812325*8.20681165367255E-05"

Output :"10993.657030812325*0.0000820681165367255"

The complexity I am facing is to detect it inside a mathematical expression.

The regular expression that detects a regular expression i have is:

```
(([1-9][0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)|(\.[0-9]+))([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?
```

However that matches true for the entire expression, is there direct way to solve this or do i have to break it down and check individually.

Comment: Why would you ever use a regular expression for this? Anyway, you can use a regex to match it and then execute custom code to convert it. I'm sure the .NET regex library has a replace function that can invoke a callback.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Enlighten pls, how else can it be done, I am open to a non regex soloution as well

Comment: @ThiefMaster I'd like to see one if it worked! (And yes, you're right, [it does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx).)

Comment: It seems, that Regex is the very tool to replace floating point values with formatted ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing, that exponent is not too large (less than 99) you can 
use this code:

```
  String formula = "10993.657030812325*8.20681165367255E-05";
  String pattern = @"(([1-9][0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)|(\.[0-9]+))([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)"; 

  // Let's change format of each double precision in the formula:
  String result = Regex.Replace(formula, pattern, (match) => {
    // Simple formating; may be you should use more elaborated one
    Double db = Double.Parse(match.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    // Now, you should format out the Double db:
    // First eliminate exponent (F99 is the maximum possible; F100 won't do) 
    String St = db.ToString("F99", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    // Next eliminate trailing '0' 
    if (St.IndexOf('.') >= 0)
      St = St.TrimEnd('0');

    return St.TrimEnd('.'); 
  });
```

The result is "10993.6570308123*0.0000820681165367255"

Comment: I wouldn't use `double` for this. For example, `31.0000000000000480*31.0000000000000480E-05` becomes `31.0000000000001*0.00031`.

Comment: slight improvement; now it's `31.00000000000005*0.00031000000000000049`. Also the `99` in `R99` is [ignored](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#RFormatString).

Comment: @Rawling: I see, you're quite right: in order to do the work exactly I'll have to implement a routine that does format on string, not on Double

Comment: @Dmitry You could use `decimal` to get up to 28-29 digits, but yeah, beyond that it'll have to be string handling... fun :)

Comment: @Rauld: I'm sorry, "F99" is the right format, not "R99" for the simplest solution. The right routine as Rawling mentioned should be based on string formatting without Double